# mySql - Finding customers near a specific city

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to craft a query to find all customers within X miles of a given city and state, using basically the following table structure:

```
Users Table
-----------
ID

PersonsName

ZipCode
```

```
Zipcodes Table (contains all ZIPs in the US)
--------------------------------------------
ID

ZipCode

City

State

latitude

longitude
```

It would be easy to find nearby users if I already know the lat/lng for the city I am interested in, as in the following query:

```
SELECT ID from Users u
JOIN Zipcodes z1 ON u.zipcode = z1.zipcode
WHERE 
COS(SIN(PI()*z1.latitude/180.0)*SIN(PI()*[desired latitude]/180.0)+COS(PI()*z1.latitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*[desired latitude]/180.0)*COS(PI()*[desired longitude]/180.0-PI()*z1.longitude/180.0))*3963.0 <= [desired distance]
```

However, I want to be able to use City names and State abbreviations to make it easy to enter, then have the query use that lat/lng for the distance comparison.

I guess I could write two queries, the first to get the lat/lng of the desired city, then the second to use the results to find uses within a certain distance of the lat/lng pair returned, but can it be combined into one single query that gets the proper lat/lng for the city match and then uses it in the distance calculation which is in the WHERE clause?

Cannot figure out how to craft it so that the lat/lng can be found for a city and then used in the same query for distance.

Hoping to be able to have one of our employees be able to simply enter e city/state and a desired distance and the code returns all customers that apply.  The code would only get the first match for a particular city (there may be many entries in the ZIP table for larger cities), but that is fine for our purposes (and thus we could just use the first match).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need some geocoding in there, to translate city names into coordinates. Lots of good APIs are available (Google, Algolia, Mapbox etc)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that geocoding will handle a large portion of edge cases not covered by this query but if you are looking for a quick and dirty fix using just the tools you have on hand I believe the following query will work for you.

```
SELECT ID from Users u
  JOIN Zipcodes z1 ON u.zipcode = z1.zipcode
  join (select latitude as desired_latitude, longitude as desired_longitude from Zipcodes limit 1 where City = '[user input]' and State = '[user input]' limit 1)
WHERE
  COS(SIN(PI()*z1.latitude/180.0)*SIN(PI()*[desired latitude]/180.0)+COS(PI()*z1.latitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*[desired latitude]/180.0)*COS(PI()*[desired longitude]/180.0-PI()*z1.longitude/180.0))*3963.0 <= [desired distance];
```

Though assuming your User table will have more rows in it than you Zipcodes table you would probably want to refactor that query to be something like this:

```
SELECT ID from Users u
  JOIN (
          select z1.zipcode from Zipcodes z1
          join (select latitude as desired_latitude, longitude as desired_longitude from Zipcodes limit 1 where City = '[user input]' and State = '[user input]' limit 1)
          WHERE COS(SIN(PI()*z1.latitude/180.0)*SIN(PI()*desired_latitude/180.0)+COS(PI()*z1.latitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*desired_latitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*desired_longitude/180.0-PI()*z1.longitude/180.0))*3963.0 <= [desired distance]
       ) as zipsInRange ON u.zipcode = zipsInRange.zipcode;
```